# FTPSclient not working properly on new FTPS server

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client, lucee

We will be moving to our own ftps server in the near future from a customer's ftps server. I just tried the existing code but it doesn't work correctly with our new server.

The login seems to work and I can use `printWorkingDirectory()` and see that I'm in the correct directory on the server. But we can't upload files or list the files in the working directory. `listFiles()` and `printWorkingDirectory()` return an empty string or an empty array, although files are in the working directory.

IIRC we had similar issues on the old FTPS server and could fix it by entering passive mode. But neither `enterLocalPassiveMode()` nor `enterLocalActiveMode()` work. Also leaving that line out completely doesn't help

The server itself works fine when connecting with FileZilla, so I guess the problem lies within our code but since we don't get an error message it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Here's the version that worked on the old server (using cfscript on Lucee 5.1.2.24):

```
var oFTPSclient = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient").init("ssl",false);
oFTPSclient.connect( 'our.ftp.server');
oFTPSclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
oFTPSclient.login( 'user', 'password');

var qFiles = DirectoryList(
    path = '/path/to/files/to/upload',
    filter = "*.jpg",
    listInfo = "query"
);

// Upload files
for( var oFile IN qFiles) {
    // Create path to source file
    var sSourceFilePath = ExpandPath( oFile.directory & '/' & oFile.name);
    // Create java file object
    var oJavaFile = CreateObject( "java", "java.io.File").init( sSourceFilePath);
    // open input stream from file
    var oFileInputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init( oJavaFile);
    // Set file transfer to binary
    oFTPSclient.setFileType( oFTPSclient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    // store current file to server
    oFTPSclient.storeFile( oFile.name, oFileInputStream);
    oFileInputStream.close();
}

oFTPSclient.disconnect();
```

When we try to upload files, the loop finishes, but way to quickly (our connection is rather slow here, so a few megabytes should not be uploaded instantly) and the `disconnect()` call at the end times out.

Any ideas where to start debugging? Or is my initial assumption that it's a problem with the code wrong and it's a problem with the server and we should rather look into that?

**Update:**

Due to the length, I have posted FileZilla's verbose log here: http://pastebin.com/b9TfR7cg

Comment: If it works against the old server and not the new server then it sounds like a configuration difference between the two servers. For example, has the new server got a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: Show us FileZilla verbose log file.

Comment: Here's FileZilla's verbose log: https://pastebin.com/b9TfR7cg

Comment: Do you have an access to server-side log? + What does `getReplyString()` return after `listFiles()` + Does it work with plain insecure FTP?

Comment: `listFiles()` returns `503 Rejected--secure connection required` - which seems to be a misspelled error code, 530 seems to be correct for that error. Can it be that I need to request secure mode manually since I'm in explicit mode? If so, is there an example on how to do that?

Comment: We were not able to find out what the problem was so we tried out [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) as client and that worked without any problems.